# Symfony and Doctrine2 - get info from annotations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity `User` with field `userName` (with appriopriate getter and setter) which maps to field `user_name` in table `users`. In `UserRepository` I fetch one record from database and I have `$user` of class `User`. How can I find out table and field name for `$user->userName` ? I need somehow to fetch information from annotations. I found that this information is in Doctrine2 cache and I found [class ClassMetadataInfo documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html) but I don't know how to put it together.

Comment: Would you mind sharing informations on why you need it. Most of the time if you need this kind of information there is a better way, letting the ORM handle the issues of mapping.

Comment: I have an Entity assigned to table1 but I want to save information from this entity in table2 which has more columns than table1.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to get the class metadata of a specific class by doing so:

```
$entityManager->getClassMetadata(get_class($user))
```